# Rails delete not working inside twitter bootstrap dropdown (2.1.0)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just upgraded the gem less-rails-bootstrap to use twitter bootstrap 2.1.0, and it seems to have broken this code in my view, inside a bootstrap dropdown:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_admin_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

The server seems to think this is a GET request instead of a DELETE. However, if I take that view code and put it immediately outside the dropdown, then it works great and the server recognizes the DELETE request.

If I change my gemfile as such:

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '~> 2.0.4'
```

Then run 'bundle update' and restart the server, then everything works as expected again. But if I simply have:

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
```

Then run 'bundle update' and restart the server, then the server thinks the DELETE is a GET request.

I tried switching to the gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', and the exact same issue occurs. I assume I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause is here, but it might have to do with the fact that rails uses javascript to simulate a form when you specify `:method => :delete` on a link using `link_to`. See the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for details. Maybe something added in the new bootstrap conflicts with that javascript.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I'm still hoping that this is not the case. I haven't found anyone else reporting this same issue, but it could be because bootstrap 2.1.0 hasn't been out very long.

Comment: Notice that no javascript called inside the dropdown works. In your signout link_to, add

`confirm: "Logout?"`

and notice it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, it's a Twitter Bootstrap issue. Probably will be fixed in the next release. Here, try this quick fix:

```
$('body')
  .off('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown')
  .on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() });
```

Comment: Thanks. Just unbinding the propagation-stopping handler with the `off` call was enough for me.

Comment: Dude! Awesome. Marc, just put in a `$(function() { ...});` block in your application.js file.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently others are having the same issue as well: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4688

The quick fix with devise for now seems to be to change devise.rb to include:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Comment: This will work, but it's generally considered an anti-pattern to have your application logout exposed via a GET. A few concrete reasons - web proxies and browsing accelerators may prefetch links to your logout endpoint inadvertently logging the user out. And anywhere on the Internet that a user can post an img tag they post one that points to your login endpoint, logging out your users.